# Reduce text output of command-line render

Tags: rendering, command-line

When executing something like `blender -b project.blend -a` a line for each object `syncing objectxy1`, `syncing objectxy2` and `rendering 1 / 128 samples`, `rendering 26 / 128 samples` (and so on) is written to the command-line.

**Is it possible to limit the log to less output or even no output?**
Maybe by using some `-verbose=0` switch or something similar?

*Some background:*

In my case I am rendering a relatively simple EEVEE animation with blender 2.80.75 created with animation nodes (AN). However, there are about 5000 Objects created with AN (but it shouldn't matter where they are coming from). When I render within blender itself it takes about 2s per frame, but interrupts rendering at some random frame causing blender to crash and close (for whatever reason). The reason for that shouldn't be the matter of the question though. Rendering via command-line works without any crashes, but takes much longer!

When rendering via command-line, it takes 8s alone to write 5000 lines (one for each object which is synced) to the command-line, before doing a roughly 1s render. In generel, writing a lot of text to the command-line could slow done a program significantly and I think that is the bottleneck here. So reducing the output should decrease the time for each render dramatically.

**I tried ...**

- `--verbose 0`
- `--log-level 0`, `--log-level 1`
- `--log-file test.txt` (creates a file which stays empty without changing anything at the command-line.)

These parameters are from https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html and I tried them before and after the `-a`-parameter, and also right before `-b`. Nothing seems to have an influence on the `syncing object`-lines.

Comment: To lose all the output in a Windows environment use the redirection character to nul `blender.exe > nul`. Would be different for Mac/Linux and it might important information.

Comment: Works flawless! I haven't thought outside the (blender) box...